# Css is not reflecting in html

Tags: html, css

I have this in my .css file

```
.attachment-label {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

and I try to use it in my html like so:

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <span class="attachment-label">Attachment</span>
                    <hr style=" margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: .5rem; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);"/>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img class="card-img-top imageThumbnail" src="@TicketHeader.AttachmentPath" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It doesn't style my span. But if I put the style inline like so:

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <span style=" font-size: 10px; font-style: italic; color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);">Attachment</span>
                    <hr style=" margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: .5rem; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);"/>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img class="card-img-top imageThumbnail" src="@TicketHeader.AttachmentPath" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're loading css file properly?

Comment: The class imageThumbnail works and it is in the same css file.

Comment: Are those styles being overwritten by a more specific style? (Have you checked the CSS in the dev tools?)

Comment: That's the thing, I don't see it in the devtools. The style somehow does not load.

Comment: Could the CSS file be cached, perhaps you are seeing a version of that file without your changes?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I tried using it on another browser. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you doesn't link your .css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/your.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

Tweak your CSS like this

```
.attachment-label {
font-size: 10px;
font-style: italic;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

You need to add single space after comma and expected a leading zero

Comment: Why? How does that magically load the CSS file?

Comment: when i compiled in jsfiddle its showing some warnings, so may be it will help, and i dint see any other problem with the code.

Comment: Then please explain what you've changed, and why. Mentioning the error message might also help